# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail returning null bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to create thumbnail from the video . I am selecting video from the gallery , after selection its returning me the following path :

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/demo.mp4
```

I am giving this path as a input of createVideoThumbnail method like :

```
 bitmap =  ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

but each time it is returning me NULL bitmap with exception .There some question on SO same as this but those did not work for me . can anybody help me ?

Comment: @KunalK: excellent ! worked for me . If you put this as answer then I can accept it . And it will helpful in future .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is with the filePath that you are passing, may be you should try by passing the absoulute path of that file.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a remote URL?